# Declare custom formatted delimiters mathtools

Tags: formatting, mathtools, delimiters

First I want to thank `mathtools` package maintainers.

### Issue Description

The issue is about declaring paired delimiters with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter(X)`:
if I want to e.g. colour the delimiters (with defining a new command), the `mathtools` won't work.

**MWE:**

```latex
% ============================================================================ %
%                                   SETTINGS                                   %
% ============================================================================ %
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor} % for \textcolor command
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \DeclarePairedDelimiterX command

% Formatted paired delimiter
%
%   - coloured delimiter definition
%
\newcommand{\absdelim}{\textcolor{red}{|}}
%
%   - declare the paired delimiter with mathtools
%
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\absval}[1]{\absdelim}{\absdelim}{#1}

% ============================================================================ %
%                                     BODY                                     %
% ============================================================================ %
\begin{document}

This does not work:
\[
    \absval*{\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}}}
\]

This alone works:
\[
    \absdelim
\]

\end{document}
```

The compiler raises this: `Missing delimiter (. inserted).`

You can test with other custom commands: if the delimiter in the `\newcommand{\absdelim}` is formatted by another command, the compiler won't run.

### Question

Is there a trick to format delimiters (perhaps using `<post>` `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX`'s optional argument or by using `\DeclarePairedDelimiterPPX` command)?

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine the inner wrapper (you probably will have to redefine the `nostarnonscaled` and `nostarscaled` wrapper too, see the documentation).
`\mathcolor` requires a rather recent LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor} % for \textcolor command
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \DeclarePairedDelimiterX command

\newcommand{\absdelim}{|}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\absval[1]{\absdelim}{\absdelim}{#1}
\reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper\absval{star}{\mathcolor{red}{#1}#2\mathcolor{green}{#3}}
\begin{document}

\[
    \absval*{\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank! I accept this as the answer because it works for colour and I prefer using the command that redefines the inner wrapper than re-changing the text colour in black (several drawbacks to this).
However, my original idea was not only to change the colour but add a glossary entry link onto the delimiters, but this is another question (it does not work because of \glshyperlink command behaviour)

Comment: As David wrote, `\left` and `\right` don't like to be in a group so you are quite restricted in what you can put around them (`\textcolor` in my example wouldn't work because of this.)

Comment: @vepain instead of black in mine you could use a saved color using `\colorlet` from xcolor

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I see, the issue is on `\left` `\right` behaviour, is there a more flexible way to simulate `\left` `\right` with formatted delimiters (hyper-linkable, coloured etc.) ?
If there is no way, I will use manual delimiter sizes (e.g. \big).
---
@DavidCarlisle yes, this is what I actually do

Answer (score 1):

`\left` and `\right` need to be in the same group, so you can not do

```
{\color{red}\left|} ....    {\color{red}\right|}
```

but you can do

```
   {\color{red}\left| {\color{black} ....    }\right|}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor} % for \textcolor command
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \DeclarePairedDelimiterX command

% Formatted paired delimiter
%
%   - coloured delimiter definition
%

%
%   - declare the paired delimiter with mathtools
%
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\absvalblack}[1]{|}{|}{#1}
\NewDocumentCommand\absval{sm}{%
 \mathcolor{red}{%
   \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\absvalblack*}{\absvalblack}{\mathcolor{black}{#2}}%
  }}
% ============================================================================ %
%                                     BODY                                     %
% ============================================================================ %
\begin{document}

This does work:
\[
    \absval*{\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}}}
\]


\end{document}
```